# Open a Google Drive file with Word using Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

When *Backup and Sync* is installed, Google Drive web allow to open a file directly in a local app installed on the computer via the "Open with > Word" context menu.

My question is: can I this feature on a web app that uses the Drive API ?

The idea is: a Word file is created on the Drive using the Drive API and then a link is rendered to the user to open the file directly in Word without having to download it or knowing the exact location and name of the file on Drive.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two ways to open files with the use of [Google Drive UI](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/integrate-open):

- The **Open with** contextual menu item
- The Google Picker dialog for opening files

[**Open files using the Open with contextual menu**](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/integrate-open#open_files_using_the_open_with_contextual_menu)

> When a user chooses files in Google Drive and selects the **Open with**
>   menu option, Drive redirects the user to the [Open URL](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/enable-sdk#open_url) for the selected
>   application (this URL is defined when you [enable the Drive platform](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/enable-sdk)).
>   The redirected request from the user's browser contains this important
>   information in the state parameter:
>
> - The `ids` of the file(s) to open (or `exportIds` when opening native Google documents)
> - The `action`, set to open.
> - The `userId` of the authenticated user.

[**Open and upload files using the Google Picker API**](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/picker)

> For details around enabling Team Drives support and adding Team Drives
>   view in file picker, see [Picker API
>   reference](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference).
>
> When a user selects a file from the list, the file ID is returned, and
>   the ID may be used by your app to access the file. You can also add to
>   a picker dialog the capability to upload files to Google Drive.

Comment: I don't want to integrate my app in the Google Drive API. What I want is to be able to open a specific file (the user allowed me to manipulate) in Word through the local copy (made available through the backup and sync app).
Just the way OneDrive allow me to open a specific file in my local Word.